# What syntax is used for "Custom Parameters" in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal

I have published to ArcGIS Portal a Map Image Layer containing 3 layers. Each layer contains some overhead and underground (UG) assets. Usually, I would just make a definition query to only select the UG by attribute. It seems that Map Image Layers behave differently than other feature types. Instead of the usual options in ArcGIS, I have this limited subset:

[image: a]

I had thought I could just select the UG attribute here in the Custom Parameters, but I cannot seem to find the proper syntax to query here. My searches about custom parameters all seem to  hit on a url based API instead of editing the layer properties in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Have you looked at this [page](https://esribelux.com/2021/04/23/filter-data-wfs-in-arcgis-pro/)?

Comment: My case looks similar to example 3. At any rate, parameter = "FID", value = "3110" changes nothing. No combination of Field as parameter and Value as value changed the data output. Maybe because my layer is not a WFS, and the fields are different?